# App Crashing for lower than lollipop while setting up Digits

Tags: android, sdk, twitter-fabric

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: mainProcess: com.easy.easypackage, PID: 17362
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io.fabric.sdk.android.InitializationTask
    at io.fabric.sdk.android.Kit.<init>(Kit.java:45)
    at com.twitter.sdk.android.core.TwitterCore.<init>(TwitterCore.java:69)
    at com.twitter.sdk.android.core.TwitterCore.<init>(TwitterCore.java:63)
    at com.easy.easypackage.utils.AppApplication.onCreate(AppApplication.java:22)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1013)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4730)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:175)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1368)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5602)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I have setup digits and everything works fine for lolipop and above version devices but crashes on lower version devices from kitkat.

Answer (score 0):

Todd from Fabric. It is important to note that Digits 2.0 supports Android 14+. Please do not upgrade to Digits 2.0 if your project needs to be built for Android versions less than 14. [Check out this page for details.](https://docs.fabric.io/android/digits/upgrading.html)